# What are the conformal killing vector fields on $S^2$ equipped with the round metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, spherical-coordinates, conformal-geometry

What are the conformal killing vector fields on $S^2$ equipped with the round metric? (expressed in the standard coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$) The space of conformal killing vector fields make a 6 dimensional vector space, so I am asking for a simple basis expressed in the standard coordinates. (I know $\sin \phi \partial_{\phi}$ is one of them, which is conformal Killing but not Killing).

The space of conformal diffeomorphisms of $S^2$ is known to be the set of Mobius transformations, which is a 6-parameter family. Is there a way to compute the conformal killing vector fields from the Mobius transformations?

If there is a reference you know that lists them, please share them.

Comment: These are best described by identifying $S^2$ with the Riemann sphere ${\mathbb C}\cup \{\infty\}$. Then theses fields are of the form $(az^2 + bz+c)\partial_z$, where $a, b, c\in {\mathbb C}$. From this, you can use the stereographic projection to get a formula on the round sphere in terms of the spherical coordinates. I do not expect the answer to be particularly nice.